# What Type (class) do i use for a property in my POCO for Asp.net Identy User

Tags: ef-code-first, poco, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a codefirst POCO, and i want to specify a LastEditUser from my current ASP.NET IDENTITY user. I tried type ApplicationUser that gets generated with the new project. but it just saves as null.

Here is my current Attempt

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser LastEditMember { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how i try to save it in my controller.

```
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
instannceOfSomeClass.LastEditMember = currentUser;
```

After loading this again. the LastEditMember property is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the UserManager class to get the user object instead of working with the DbContext object. You can use UserManager.FindByIdAsync(currentUserId) to get the user. Also I am considering that this code is hit only after a user logs into the application else the currentUserId will be null

Comment: I tried using the UserManager, it still just returns an ApplicationUser. When i set my LastEditMember property equal to this AplicationUser and save, everything seems fine, but when you load the entity again, the LastEditMember is null again... so i am still stuck on the exact same spot. Anything else i can try?

Comment: Ok, I see in the Database, it actualy did save the user id in the LastEditMember Column. The User is just not loading into the LastEditMember property when the SomeClass entity is loaded.

Comment: Your class should follow EF conventions to store and retrieve custom types from DB. My first hunch would be to make it virtual and see if that works. Else follow this link to create the model in the way EF expects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

Comment: Thanks, The virtual was what i needed! and that link is also going to help me in the future